# How do I access ALL window objects from a Chrome extension?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am developing a Chrome extension for work, and one of the things it needs to do is to read (only read, not modify) an object that we send back to the website after it makes an asynchronous request to our servers. Basically I need to read the `window.<our object name>` object and get what's in there.

Now, I know this is possible, because I did this in a Tampermonkey script that I wrote. I was able to `console.log(window.<our object name>)` and it came in.

Tampermonkey is a Chrome extension, so there's no intrinsic reason why it can access something and another extension can't.

But when I try to access this object, both from content scripts and from injected code, I get nothing. When I get the `window` object only, it comes up only partially, as if the extension were blind to certain parts of it. But if I'm in the console on the page, and I call `window`, I get a full window object back. Infuriating.

So if content scripts don't work, and injected scripts don't work, and there's no reason why popup scripts would be any good here, how does one do this?

Many thanks!

UPDATE: As requested, here is the manifest.json (I took the page_redder example and worked off that to make sure I wasn't making any weird mistakes):

```
{
  "name": "Page Redder",
  "description": "Make the current page red",
  "version": "2.0",
  "permissions": [
    "activeTab"
  ],
  "background": {
    "scripts": ["background.js"],
    "persistent": false
  },
  "browser_action": {
    "default_title": "get my object"
  },
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
      "js": ["content.js"]
    }
  ],
  "manifest_version": 2
}
```

And here is content.js:

```
var getWindow = window.setTimeout(function() { console.log("From content script: " + window.<OBJECT NAME>); }, 5000);
```

And here is background.js:

```
// Copyright (c) 2011 The Chromium Authors. All rights reserved.
// Use of this source code is governed by a BSD-style license that can be
// found in the LICENSE file.    

// Called when the user clicks on the browser action.
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
  // No tabs or host permissions needed!
  chrome.tabs.executeScript({
    code: 'console.log("From injected script:" + window.<OBJECT NAME>);'
  });
});
```

When run, I get:

From content script: undefined
From injected script: undefined

But if I do window. from the console, I get it. I even added a timeout to make sure that the content script wasn't trying to get something that hadn't loaded in yet. But I can retrieve the object manually before the script runs, and it still gives me undefined.

Comment: Can you include `javascript` , `manifest.json` at Question?

Comment: Yeah, definitely. Done.

Comment: injected scripts can read what you want. you likely have timing issues.

Comment: What does `console.log(window)` log?

Comment: It logs a window object that is missing the objects I'm looking for. I'd like to say it's timing issues, but the injected script runs on icon press, and I'm waiting for the page to fully load before pressing it.

Comment: So if it's not timing issues, could it be permissions? I gave it activeTab, which I thought would cover the window object.

Answer (score 6):

Soo, this is kind of hacky, but I was able to do it and it worked.

To gain access to everything available to the host `window`, I had to create a `script` element, put all the code I wanted in there, and add `document.body.appendChild(script)` for it to work.

Not the sexiest way of doing things, but it will get the job done for small tasks.

Comment: I have looked for it all over the internet and couldn't find anything. You, sir, just made my day. Thank you!

Comment: Glad to help, @DiegoFortes!

Answer (score 0):

Interesting question. Here is a quick and probably incomplete answer :

- each tab has its own private separate `window` object
- `background.js` also has its own
- content scripts are a bit tricky in that while they nominally live inside the page, they actually keep a respectful distance : see [isolated worlds](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts#execution-environment)
- I am not familiar with `chrome.tabs.executeScript` but somehow I would'nt trust it with anything beyond basics

One approach could be as follow :

Open the relevant page from the background script with `chrome.tabs.create` : hence the backgound will have complete control and dominance over said tab and the `window`, `document` and `your_object` therein. It will also be easier to handle the asynchronous side of thing : you'll learn to love [callbacks](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/js-ctypes/Using_js-ctypes/Declaring_and_Using_Callbacks).

Depending on what is required regarding the UX, another option would be to handle the async request, and fetch `your_object`, entirely in `background.js`

One last hint : extensions you download from the store are just zipped files in your Chrome profile. Find `tapermonkey.crx` or whatever, unzip it and read the sources to figure out what it does.

And oh, relying on timeout to handle asynchronicity is bound to random results.

Comment: Oh really? I will try that

Answer (score -2):

According to documentation in https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts

> However, content scripts have some limitations. They **cannot**:
>
> - Use variables or functions defined by web pages or by other content scripts.

So you can access the common window variables from the content script, but not the variables created from the webpage's javascript, another content script or, as in your case, an object you have sent to the website.

Comment: Apparently you can, because Tampermonkey does it. I just have to figure out how.

Comment: this does not answer the question as its not considering injected scripts that op mentions