# chromium "application/x-google-chrome-pdf" how to extract height of pdf by javascript?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I'm trying to extract height of `document`, while browsing `pdf` with chromium's default pdf-viewer extension.

There are two DevTools possible to open, one - DevTools of `Tab`, need to open before opening pdf:

```
> document.querySelectorAll("embed")[0].type
"application/pdf"
```

And second, after extension complete pdf loading:

```
> document.querySelectorAll("embed")[0].type
"application/x-google-chrome-pdf"
```

There are common trick to extract `height`:

```
var body = document.body;
var html = document.documentElement;
var height = Math.max( body.scrollHeight, body.offsetHeight, html.clientHeight, html.scrollHeight, html.offsetHeight );
```

Extension's DevTools tells me: `432,853`, but DevTools of Tab, gives me only `848`.

Off-course, the right one - is 432,853. And me needs it, I want to get it in my own chrome's extension. While, I'm able extract height on any web-page or text file from disk `file://`, the pdf - is only one big black-box, that I can not hack yet. Please, help!

I know about isolated words, from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36672980/how-do-i-access-all-window-objects-from-a-chrome-extension), and I've googled alot around. But there shall be such trick, like getting `window`'s scroll's toddler size or something like that...